# логическая ошибка в операторе функтора

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Nnumber : std::unary_function<char, bool>{
    static int k;
public:
    bool operator ()(char ch) {
        if (isdigit(ch))
            return false;
        if ( ch == ',' || ch == '.') {
            ++k;
            if(k < 2)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

};
int Nnumber::k = 0;
void remake(string& s) {
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), Nnumber()), s.end());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication qca(argc, argv);
    string s("123, rt45,6j"), s1("567,.. 87");
    remake(s);
    remake(s1);
    cout << s <<'\n'  // "123,457"
         << s1;       // "56787" ??? нет символа ','
    return qca.exec();
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы строка представляла рациональное число произвольной длины, а для этого пытаюсь исключать любой попавший там ненужный символ.
Я ожидал, что  s1 == "567,87", однако это не так. Никак не разобрался в чем ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста исправить

Comment: В качестве побочного замечания: `std::unary_function` является deprecated и использовать ее больше нет необходимости.

Comment: @AnT,  спасибо, буду знать

Comment: ... если я не ошибаюсь, в С++17 `std::unary_function` и `std::binary_function` уже нет вообще.

Comment: @AnT,  может быть, поскольку  там говорят много  чего нового (я не смотрел еще -  я всего лишь новычок )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логично, потому что k - у Вас статическая переменная, и между разными вызовами ее значение сохраняется. Не забывайте её обнулять и все будет ок.

P.S.

код вида

```
if(k < 2)
  return false;
else
  return true;
```

лучше заменить на

```
return (k>=2);
```

Comment: согласен, но это просто улучшение записи, а не исправление логической ошибки, простите, поспешил ! наало не прочитал...

Comment: а в каком месте обнулять ?

Comment: добавил условие в вопросе

Comment: обнулять переменную наверно нужно в вызове remake (только k приватная, поэтому либо нужно делать публичной, либо сделать функцию для этого). В этом случае возвращает ожидаемый Вами результат. Но лучше конечно сделать переменную не статической и обнулять в конструкторе. Но там результат другой, а мне не хочется понимать почему.

Улучшение, которое я предложил в коде, это именно улучшение и упрощение (а я и не писал, что это исправление ошибки).

Comment: я понел, спасибо - упустил что после первого вызова  статитческий член уже изменен...

Comment: посмотрите исправленный код. По моему вы это имели ввиду

Comment: код лучше перенесите в вопрос, а не отдельным ответом. И обнуление переменной k лучше делать до вызова, а не после (хотя это на результат и не повлияет)

Comment: ок, но только не понел как код перенести в вопрос.... Ну да ладно, вы ответили на мой вопрос, и спасибо вам

Comment: Скобки тут как бы тоже лишние.

Answer (score 0):

?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Nnumber : std::unary_function<char, bool>{
public:
    Nnumber(): k(0) {}
    bool operator ()(char ch) {
        if (isdigit(ch))
            return false;
        if ( ch == ',' || ch == '.') {
            ++k;
            if(k < 2)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

};
void remake(string& s) {
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), Nnumber()), s.end());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication qca(argc, argv);
    string s("123, rt45,6j"), s1("567,.. 87");
    remake(s);
    remake(s1);
    cout << s <<'\n'  // "123,457"
         << s1;       // "56787" ??? нет символа ','
    return qca.exec();
}
```

Comment: с вашим кодом все запятые и точки будут в строке, а нужно, чтобы осталась только первая запятая или точка. Извените, сейчась добавлю в вопрос

Answer (score -1):

```
  struct Nnumber : std::unary_function<char, bool>{
    static int k;
    bool operator ()(char ch) {
        if (isdigit(ch))
            return false;
        if ( ch == ',' || ch == '.') {
            ++k;
            return k >= 2;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
int Nnumber::k = 0;
void remake(string& s) {
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), Nnumber()), s.end());
    Nnumber::k = 0;
}
```